# python3 -m switch files

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

If I run this on my (Linux) command line.

```
python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports
```

I get the result:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0        
1 ports found.
```

What files (or sequence of files) are run by this `-m` switch?

I have various python directories in my `/usr/` directory but no specific `serial.py` file (I can see `serialcli.py` & `serialutil.py`, `serialize.py` etc) so the command is being 'turned' into some form to use a 'serial based' file, but which one?.

How does it generate the output?

In python code when I use this command no output is generated so I guess the `-m` switch taps into an output routine??

The output from this command (and other examples) is quite useful and I may want to use it in python itself rather than from BASH.

I am aware it's not meant for this but for testing purposes, but still... ;)

Q: So what files are actually 'tapped into' in this 'serial' example?

Comment: For example, this article will be helpful for how to use it. [Python serial.tools.list_ports.comports() Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97508/serial.tools.list_ports.comports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-m` flag in python is used for:
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

What does "terminates option list" mean?
It means that, any future options get passed to the program you are providing and not to python.

So in your scenario, it's running the `list_ports` module as a script

```
python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports
```

How can you use it in python itself?

1. You can `import` the `serial` module and call functions inside `list_ports`. I am very sure, you have these files in your workspace / environment, because you have installed `pyserial`
2. Alternatively - you can also install `pyserial` in a virtual environment, and run some experiments.

If you "really, really" want to use this like a `bash` command, within a `python` script? Do take a look at the `subprocess` module.

[Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

[Pyserial - serial.tools.list_ports](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.list_ports)

Comment: @Micklos, Hope this gives you perspective.

Comment: Thanks :D
I know I can do regular coding, e.g. import serial etc...  to eventually get similar output, but that -m one-liner is ultra efficient and I'd like to use it & other instances.; I read it's not really for that purpose, but personally for modules that are unlikely to change, I'd like to do it.

When you say "(terminates option list)" can you expand upon what that actually means? Is it that the "serial.tools.list_ports" command doesn't need extra parameters/arguments?

Also, (sorry),  could you tell me what file I should look at to see the exact "list_ports" code?

Comment: Sure. This is the file, you need for the `list_ports` code.
https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/tools/list_ports.py

Comment: You would still need to install the `pyserial` library to call the module as a script. Nevertheless, if you still want to call it in `python` like how you would do in `bash` - You should check out the `subprocess` module. Although, merely importing it, and calling the function is a lot easier.

Comment: Btw - "terminates options list" - means:
any future options get passed to the program you are providing and not to python

Comment: Tq Hariharan. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Thats really helpful tenacity. Thank you.